# Camera resolution CamcorderProfile not found in some Android phones

Tags: android, android-camera

I have a code example:

```
mediaRecorder = new MediaRecorder();
mediaRecorder.setPreviewDisplay(surfaceHolder.getSurface());
mediaRecorder.setCamera(camera);
mediaRecorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.CAMCORDER);
mediaRecorder.setVideoSource(MediaRecorder.VideoSource.CAMERA);
mediaRecorder.setProfile(CamcorderProfile.get(CamcorderProfile.QUALITY_480P));
```

This seems to work fine, as well as CamcorderProfile.QUALITY_LOW

But when I trying to get 360p video, and using CamcorderProfile.QUALITY_CIF (int = 3), I get en error in Sony Xperia Z3 (android 6.0.1)

```
MediaProfiles: The given camcorder profile camera 0 quality 3 is not found
System.err: java.lang.RuntimeException: Error retrieving camcorder profile params
System.err:     at android.media.CamcorderProfile.native_get_camcorder_profile(Native Method)
System.err:     at android.media.CamcorderProfile.get(CamcorderProfile.java:471)
System.err:     at android.media.CamcorderProfile.get(CamcorderProfile.java:402)
<...>
```

Does AOSP test suite still have not tests for SDK camera quality constants? What constants can I use in production and expect all phones (at least from 5.0) support it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> But when I trying to get 360p video, and using CamcorderProfile.QUALITY_CIF (int = 3), I get en error in Sony Xperia Z3 (android 6.0.1)

If you called [`hasProfile()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/CamcorderProfile.html#hasProfile(int)), to see if the profile was supported, and it returned `true`, but you still got this crash, then there is bug in the device firmware.

If you did not call `hasProfile()`, or you ignored its result, then there is a bug in your app.

> What constants can I use in production and expect all phones (at least from 5.0) support it?

I do not believe that this is officially documented. I *think* that `QUALITY_LOW` and `QUALITY_HIGH` should always exist, though the output from them may or may not work.